# Set UIImageView size programatically withing a UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UIColleciton view with various cells, each cell has an UIImageView within the cell.

Each cell is having a different size set programatially by using a simple select case within the below override to vary the size

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However I'm trying to set the UIImageView's size to a match the cell size at the same time (ideally by setting the x,y in the same was as the cell), is there anything you can do within the above method to accompany this or is there another override method required?